# How to do this? if else structuring. VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently making a vbs that gives you 4 letters and you can enter one of them in an input box and depending on the letter it will run a certain program. I have this so far

```
Dim Input

A=Notepad
B=Paint

Input = InputBox("Please enter one of the listed letters!" & vbNewLine & "A. Notepad" & vbNewline & "B. Paint" & vbNewLine & "C." & vbNewLine & "D.", "Abracadabra")
```

and then if they entered A as an example it would run this script.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "c:\windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

My problem however is I can't get and if else structure working to support all 4 letters and stuff. I have no idea how to do this for syntax and how I'd structure it.

Thanks in advance
-Flare

Answer (score 0):

See documentation.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84).aspx

you could try something like:

```
If Input = "A" Then
    ...
ElseIf Input = "B" Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a ton! Do you happen to know how I can have for elses? Like have four elseifs? So I can keep going? So If Input equaled C as an example it would open cmd.exe or what ever? Like is there a way to have more else statements? Thanks again! -Flare